# Convert dictionary into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
my_dict = {'product1' : [1, 511, 31, 222, 9020], 'product2' : [92, 511, 314, 4324], 'product3' : [40, 17, 4324]}
```

I want to create a dataframe that has the products as the index and the column names should be a range from 1 - 10 000, and if the value list associated to the product has the number it should be marked as a 1 or True in the column for the respective number.

```
            1    2    3    ... 4324 .... 9020
product1    1                              1
product2                         1
product3                         1
```

This entire dictionary has 80 products, each associated with a list of 0 to maybe a maximum of 50 numbers. The numbers could range between 1 and 10 000.

I would really appreciate any hints, I haven't managed to found a good way. I know I can create a dataframe from dictionary with pandas.DataFrame.from_dict() but it doesn't really do what I want.

I did a "ugly" solution, but I'm guessing this is not best practice or pythonic:

```
column_names = list(range(0,10000))

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    x = pd.Series(np.ones(len(v), dtype=int), index =v, name=k)
    df = df.append(x)
    
print(df.head())
```

which outputs

```
          0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     ...  \
product1   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
product2   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
product3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   

          9990  9991  9992  9993  9994  9995  9996  9997  9998  9999  
product1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
product2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
product3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  

[3 rows x 10000 columns]
```

Comment: do you really want to create a dataframe with 10000 columns? expected output is not clear

Comment: Yes 10 000 columns is the expected output. The column each represent a feature of the product. Think of it like 3495 represent a feature for the product, lets say the product described are cars, then 3495 could represent right hand drive etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be to use start by constructing a dataframe from the dictionary via the alternative constructor `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`, which handles arrays of different length setting `orient='index'`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')
```

Then use[`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) over all columns:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=df.columns, prefix='', prefix_sep='')
df.columns = pd.to_numeric(df.columns).astype(int)
df.T.groupby(level=0).max().T.reindex(range(df.columns.max()), axis=1)

            0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   ...  \
product1   NaN     1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
product2   NaN     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   
product3   NaN     0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   

          9010  9011  9012  9013  9014  9015  9016  9017  9018  9019  
product1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
product2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
product3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: That's a very nice solution!  I like it because I don't have to iterate over the dictionary.

Comment: I noticed one thing though, there is no 9020 column?

Comment: Think there was smth wrong, can't remember now tbh :) @anky

Answer (score 1):

Use the `from_dict` method with `orient='index'`:

```
my_dict = {
    'product1' : [1, 511, 31, 222, 9020],
    'product2' : [92, 511, 314, 4324],
    'product3' : [40, 17, 4324]
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
           0    1     2       3       4
product1   1  511    31   222.0  9020.0
product2  92  511   314  4324.0     NaN
product3  40   17  4324     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_dict = {'product1' : [1, 511, 31, 222, 9020], 'product2' : [92, 511, 314, 4324], 'product3' : [40, 17, 4324]}

res = []
for x in my_dict:
    arr = [np.nan] * 10000
    for y in my_dict[x]:
      arr[y - 1] = 1
    res.append(arr)
df = pd.DataFrame(res, index=my_dict.keys())

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
          0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20    21    22    23    24    25    26    27    28    29    30    31    32    33    34    35    36    37    38    39    40    41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49    50    51    52    53    54    55    56    57    58    59    60    61    62    63    64    65    66    67    68    69    70    71    72    73    74    75    76    77    78    79    80    81    82    83    84    85    86    87    88    89    90    91    92    93    94    95    96    97    98    99    100   101   102   103   104   105   106   107   108   109   110   111   112   113   114   115   116   117   118   119   120   121   122   123   124   125   126   127   128   129   130   131   132   133   134   135   136   137   138   139   140   141   142   143   144   145   146   147   148   149   150   151   152   153   154   155   156   157   158   159   160   161   162   163   164   165   166   167   168   169   170   171   172   173   174   175   176   177   178   179   180   181   182   183   184   185   186   187   188   189   190   191   192   193   194   195   196   197   198   199   200   201   202   203   204   205   206   207   208   209   210   211   212   213   214   215   216   217   218   219   220   221   222   223   224   225   226   227   228   229   230   231   232   233   234   235   236   237   238   239   240   241   242   243   244   245   246   247   248   249   ...  9750  9751  9752  9753  9754  9755  9756  9757  9758  9759  9760  9761  9762  9763  9764  9765  9766  9767  9768  9769  9770  9771  9772  9773  9774  9775  9776  9777  9778  9779  9780  9781  9782  9783  9784  9785  9786  9787  9788  9789  9790  9791  9792  9793  9794  9795  9796  9797  9798  9799  9800  9801  9802  9803  9804  9805  9806  9807  9808  9809  9810  9811  9812  9813  9814  9815  9816  9817  9818  9819  9820  9821  9822  9823  9824  9825  9826  9827  9828  9829  \
product1   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
product2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   
product3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   1.0   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   

          9830  9831  9832  9833  9834  9835  9836  9837  9838  9839  9840  9841  9842  9843  9844  9845  9846  9847  9848  9849  9850  9851  9852  9853  9854  9855  9856  9857  9858  9859  9860  9861  9862  9863  9864  9865  9866  9867  9868  9869  9870  9871  9872  9873  9874  9875  9876  9877  9878  9879  9880  9881  9882  9883  9884  9885  9886  9887  9888  9889  9890  9891  9892  9893  9894  9895  9896  9897  9898  9899  9900  9901  9902  9903  9904  9905  9906  9907  9908  9909  9910  9911  9912  9913  9914  9915  9916  9917  9918  9919  9920  9921  9922  9923  9924  9925  9926  9927  9928  9929  9930  9931  9932  9933  9934  9935  9936  9937  9938  9939  9940  9941  9942  9943  9944  9945  9946  9947  9948  9949  9950  9951  9952  9953  9954  9955  9956  9957  9958  9959  9960  9961  9962  9963  9964  9965  9966  9967  9968  9969  9970  9971  9972  9973  9974  9975  9976  9977  9978  9979  9980  9981  9982  9983  9984  9985  9986  9987  9988  9989  9990  9991  9992  9993  9994  9995  9996  9997  9998  9999  
product1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
product2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  
product3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```